# BigQueryInsertJobOperator Unable to insert 100 million rows via Airflow

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, airflow

I have tried using BigQueryInsertJobOperator operator in airflow for inserting data into table, It works completely fine for 1-2 rows.

My sql has 100 million rows , the task for the operators run completely with status as successful even creates the table but table is **empty**

```
task2 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="insert_query_job",
    gcp_conn_id='xxxxxxxxx',
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": my_sql_query,
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "destinationTable": {
                        "projectId": "xxxxxxxx",
                        "datasetId": 'yyyyyyyy',
                        "tableId": 'zzzzzzzzz'
                    },
            "allowLargeResults":True

        }
    }
    )
```

Comment: Hello, could it be that you are hitting some Bigquery limits [1]? I'm thinking of "Maximum response size", but anyway please make sure you are within all limits. 

On the other hand, could you share a sanitized version of your query?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas